# Relationship between Micro Frontends (MFE) and Backend for Frontend (BFF)

Tags: architecture, microservices, api-gateway, micro-frontend, self-contained

I think that it is common consensus that each **frontend-type** should normally have an own BFF (see https://samnewman.io/patterns/architectural/bff and figure below).

But what about micro frontends (MFE)? I read that each MFE also should have a BFF.

My understanding is that MFEs are (complete) **pages** and **fragments** (which are composed to pages, while a page is also a fragment).

I would agree that each page should have a BFF, because a page is like a normal UI. What about fragments? Does each fragment have its own BFF?

[image]